# "null" (zero) vs. "NULL"

Tags: difference

How do German software developers tell the difference between a result of zero and NULL?  They both translate to the same word..."null".  Obviously you can see the difference on the screen.

But what about when another developer asks for the results of a SQL query, and you say "null"?    Does the other developer know if you really got a "NULL" result, or "null" rows returned?  Just wondering if it leads to any confusion.

Comment: The subject is always `Null`, and never `null` in German.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not aware of any German term that clearly differentiates zero and NULL.

Since in software development English is a big influence, it's quite common to use English terms directly, without translating them: "NULL" (pronounced like the english word) in a German sentence would clearly refer to NULL as opposed to zero. Fortunately the German word "null" (for zero) is pronounced quite a bit differently.

If any confusion is possible, then you can even use the English word "zero" to refer to 0 or rephrase the sentence to avoid any reference to zero or null: "Es wurden keine Zeilen zurückgegeben."

Comment: +1 for nʌl (s.v. [Nullwert](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullwert)).

Comment: A web-designer / - programmer I run into this problem pretty often and the answer posted here is exactly what usualy happens: Null is pronounces english and Zero is either pronounces german or - very often - replaced by "keine". In case you're not shure... noone will blame you if you ask to clearify.

Comment: Additionally hint: If you want to say NULL, but pronounced it as the german null or you want to be sure, that they understand you correct, then you can add *die Zahl Null*: Das Ergebnis war null, also die Zahl Null.

Comment: I also heard people using "nil", meaning NULL, but the English pronounciation is by far the most common way to differantiate.

Comment: In my programming life, "Null" referred to the *value* zero, while we tended to use "NULL pointer" for NULL references. But in daly life, that is actually not so much of a problem, because 0 = NULL (Over-simplified, but mostly true.)

Comment: @tofro I know NULL-Pointer from langauge like C. But in databases NULL is a not existing value (in opposite to an empty value).

Comment: @knut that's "leere Antwort" in my language.

Answer (score 10):

I am a software developer, so I think I can say something about that. At least in the companies I worked for, we used the English word NULL for NULL and the German word Null (Zero) for the number zero. So NULL is just a technical term for us and we don't translate a lot of them.

Comment: Agree. At all companies I worked for we always used the English NULL and never had any troubles to distinguish it from the German number zero. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a software developer, but I know sometimes "leer" ("empty") can be used as in "empty set". Perhaps someone else can shed more light on the subject.

Comment: I don't understand, why you try to answer a qurestion, that you don't understand? 'Leer' is usualy not used to describe NULL - sometimes (hardly ever) "leeres Ergebnis" is used.

Comment: I just meant that I'm not a professional developer, not that I haven't written software. I do understand what was asked and the calculations involved. I was just trying to offer an alternative from mathematics, since at the time I saw the post no one had answered yet. I'm still new here and perhaps don't yet understand the line between trying to be helpful and being inappropriate. I should have said nothing, I suppose, rather than risk a down vote. ;-)

Comment: `leer`would most of the time be understood as an empty string, which is fundamentally different from 0 and NULL.

Comment: Yeah, or as the empty set or an empty list. All of those are distinctly not-null.

Answer (score 2):

As a software developer I can say that in a situation where the context is not clear I will either pronounce the NULL english or say "null Pointer". Otherwise I would go for a german pronounced null.

I would not use "zero" for 0.

Answer (score 1):

Das Ergebnis einer SQL-Abfrage ist entweder *Null* oder *Leer*. Statt *Leer* kann man auch *Nichts* sagen.

Eine nichtinitialisierte Referenz ist meist mit Null hinreichend präzise beschrieben, weil ein Frame, eine Liste oder ein Mitarbeiter nicht 0 sein kann, also Null im Sinne von `nicht initialisiert` sein muss.

In Java kann man zwar eindeutig sagen sagen,

```
"count ist ein int Null"
```

weil `ints` nicht `null` sein können, aber ein `Integer`, der beides sein kann, macht es schwierig. Ist er `0`, so kann man sich mit Zero behelfen, aber wenn er `null` ist, ist ein gesprochenes *Nall* das praktischste.

Bei Strings versagt die wörtliche Rede vollkommen, wenn vom Kontext nicht klar wird, dass nur eines gemeint sein kann, denn jede Erklärung könnte ja wörtlich genommen werden, und nicht als Erläuterung. Zudem kann die Zahl als Ziffer oder Wort geschrieben werden.

Bei Listen kommt auch noch `Nil` dazu, welches ich nur als `Nil` kenne.

In Scala beispielsweise kennt man auch noch `Nothing` als universellen Typ, der von jedem Typ erben kann, und den ich auch noch nicht übersetzt gesehen habe.